# Another mathy question from the Signal Processing community...

Tags: calculus, trigonometric-series

[This is the question as posed to the DSP folks](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/42495/implication-of-sampling-and-reconstruction-theorem). Electrical engineers like to use particular definitions of the Fourier Transform (using Hz, rather than angular frequency) and the sinc function.

Out of consideration to you kind folks, I will try to eliminate a few symbols, like I will, without loss of generality, set the sample rate, $f_\text{s}$, to 1 and I try to use angular frequency.

So let $$ 0 < \omega_0 < \pi $$

and for *any* real $W$ such that

$$ \omega_0 < W < 2\pi - \omega_0 $$

please prove that

$$  \cos(\omega_0 t + \phi) =  \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}  \cos\left(\omega_0 n  + \phi \right) \, \frac{\sin\big( W(t - n) \big)}{\pi(t - n)} $$

**without** the use of the Fourier Transform.

I s'pose one of the [*" Whittaker–Nyquist–Kotelnikov–Shannon"* folks did this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem), but I can't see exactly how this gets extracted out of the [Poisson summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula).

I spent all of my rep on a bounty of a previous question.  Sorry, I don't have much rep to spend here.

well, **21 hours left to get the bounty!!**  don't let it go to waste.

UPDATE: the 100 rep bounty has expired.  so i guess it's wasted.

Comment: Just out of interest, why is it important to you that it is proved without the fourier transform?

Comment: And what about fourier series?

Comment: geez, i know sorta how it's done **with** the Fourier Transform.  (see the link that takes it to the DSP SE).  i just thought that with a zillion different values for $W$, the sum of the sinc functions (of width $W$) still adds up, no matter what $W$ is, as long as it's in that range.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Anything you don't understand with my answer ?

Comment: an error was pointed out to me in the formation of the question at the DSP.SE .  that required i change $W$ to $\pi$ in the denominator of the $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ factor in this question.

Answer (score 0):

- Let 
  $$f(x) = \frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x} = \int_{-1/2}^{1/2} e^{2 i\pi \xi x}d\xi, \qquad F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f(y)dy, \quad F(-\infty) = 0, \ F(+\infty) = 1$$
  If $g$ is bounded and $C^1$ then
  $$\lim_{m \to \infty}\int_{k-1/2}^{k+1/2} m f(mx) g(x)dx=\lim_{m \to \infty} F(mx) g(x)|_{k-1/2}^{k+1/2}- \int_{k-1/2}^{k+1/2}  F(mx) g'(x)dx \\ = 1_{k> -1/2} g(k+1/2)-1_{k> 1/2}g(k-1/2)-\int_{k-1/2}^{k+1/2}1_{x > 0} g'(x)dx= g(0) 1_{|k| < 1/2}$$
  (ie. $m f(mx) \to \delta(x)$ in the sense of distributions)
- Then see the [Dirichlet kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_kernel)

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{2i \pi k n}f(x-n) =\lim_{m \to \infty} \sum_{n=-m}^m e^{2i \pi k n} f(x-n) =\lim_{m \to \infty}\sum_{n=-m}^m \int_{-1/2}^{1/2} e^{2i\pi( \xi x+(k-\xi) n)}d\xi \\= \lim_{m \to \infty} \int_{-1/2}^{1/2} e^{2i\pi \xi x} \frac{\sin(2\pi(m+1/2) (k-\xi))}{\sin(\pi (k-\xi))}d\xi \\=\lim_{m \to \infty} \int_{-k-1/2}^{-k+1/2} e^{2 i\pi (\xi+k) x} \frac{\pi \xi}{\sin(\pi  \xi)}m f(m\xi) d\xi =e^{2i \pi k x} 1_{|k| < 1/2}$$

With a subtelty if $|k| = 1/2$, in that case we need a factor $1/2$.

The whole proves the Fourier series, the Fourier  transform as well as the Shannon sampling theorem !

Comment: i just wanna confirm a notation that appears to be used by the math community, but is unfamiliar to me.  is this true?: $$1_{|k|<\tfrac12} = \Pi(k)  $$ where $\Pi(u)$ (sometimes "$\operatorname{rect}(u)$") is the [rectangular function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangular_function)

$$\Pi(u) \triangleq \begin{cases}
1        \qquad & \text{ if } |u| < \tfrac12 \\
0        \qquad & \text{ if } |u| \ge \tfrac12 \\
\end{cases}$$

Comment: and $$ 1_{x \ge 0} = H(x)$$ is the [Heaviside unit step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function)
$$H(u) \triangleq \begin{cases}
1        \qquad & \text{ if } u \ge 0 \\
0        \qquad & \text{ if } u < 0 \\
\end{cases}$$ if we don't worry too much about the value at the discontinuity?

Comment: reuns, i had a mistake in the question that had to be corrected.  see my comment above.  does that change anything in your proof?